# Moving From one tab view to another by button Click Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, buttonclick, tabview

I am using http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ to make Tab bar.
I have also 3 tab first and the second Tab view contains a List view and third on e is Settings. 
Settings Contain Reload button. When I clicked the Reload Button I want to move to First Tab.
How can I do this ?

Comment: All this tabs are they fragment or just views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make following changes:

1. Pass the viewPager reference to your adapter and from adapter to your fragment:

   ```
    public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       ViewPager viewPager;
       public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ViewPager viewPager) {
           super(fm);
           this.viewPager=viewPager;  
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int index) {

           switch (index) {
           case 0:
               // Top Rated fragment activity
               return new TopRatedFragment(viewPager);
           case 1:
               // Games fragment activity
               return new GamesFragment(viewPager);
           case 2:
               // Movies fragment activity
               return new MoviesFragment(viewPager);
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           // get item count - equal to number of tabs
           return 3;
       }

   }
   ```
2. In fragment on click of button call set selection on view pager object:

   ```
    public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {
           private ViewPager viewPager;
           public  MoviesFragment (ViewPager viewPager;){
             this.viewPager=viewPager;
           }
           @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
           rootView.findViewById(<your button>).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

               }
           }); 
           return rootView;
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I know its quite late ....maybe it can help someone else...creating a constructor in fragments is not supported..so instead of passing viewpager as constructor..
we can write in the fragment on button click:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;

   /**
   * Created by medha singh on 6/17/2016.
    */
    public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {


   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_lead2, container, false);
    TextView tv=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.hardware);
    final ViewPager pager=   (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager2);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         pager.setCurrentItem(1);


        }
    });
    return view1;
   }

   }
```

So getactivity() is the solution: i got it from here:  [How to go other Tabs by clicking on a Button from the current Tab in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765884/how-to-go-other-tabs-by-clicking-on-a-button-from-the-current-tab-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
onClick(View v)
{
//Reload the data
tabHost.setCurrentTab(/*destination-tab-id*/);
}
}
)
```

Comment: This is not Working. Because here not using the Tab Host to do the tab ,here Action bar is Used.